# Showing invariance of tensor trace under $\rm SO(N)$

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, trace

If $O$ is an element of $SO(N)$, then $O$ is an $N\times N$ matrix satisfying $O^TO=1$ and det$(O)=1$.  Let tensor $T^{ij}$ be a representation of the group and let the trace be Tr$(T^{ij})=\delta^{ij}T^{ij}\equiv T$.  To show the invariance of the trace under $SO(N)$ transformations, we write

$$ T=\delta^{ij}T^{ij}\quad\longrightarrow\quad  \delta^{ij}T'^{ij}=\delta^{ij}O^{il}O^{jm}T^{lm}=(O^T)^{li}\delta^{ij}O^{jm}T^{lm}=\delta^{lm}T^{lm}=T~.$$

(Note the small prime symbol on $T$ to the right of the arrow which signifies that it is transformed.)  I want to make sure I understand the step where we insert $(O^T)^{li}$.  From the definition of the transpose, it is obvious that $O^{il}=(O^T)^{li}$.  Is that all that is being done here?  Since $\delta^{ij}$ is not a matrix, I don't think it matters where it appears in the expression.  However, since my source material (Zee's QFT) has moved $O^T$ to the other side of $\delta$, I want to make sure I'm not oversimplifying something about the algebra of the indices.  Is it as simple as the identity $O^{il}=(O^T)^{li}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that’s all that there is to it essentially. $\delta$ is a kind of matrix — it is a tensor with two indices; so a square matrix. The whole point of this step is to put an expression with contracted indices into a matrix form, where matrices are multiplied. That’s why the reordering happens — the author wants to have the last index of the previous symbol to be contracted with the first index of the current, to interpret the contraction as matrix multiplication. This condensed notation can be easier to work with that is all.